# API best practices for batch operations

Tags: api, rest, api-design

We have a requirement to develop an API with CRUD operations that supports batch inputs for each of create, read, update and delete operation.
For ex.

```
Request for "Create" will be an array of [Name and Value]
Response = array of [Name and Value]

Request for "Update" will be an array of [Name and Value] -> Values of each Name are updated here
Response = array of [Name and Value]

Request for "Delete" will be an array of Names
Response = 204 no content

Request for "Read" will be an array of Names
Response = array of [Name and Value]
```

We will use POST for Create and Update (or PUT?); However to support batch inputs (max array size=100) in the request body for Read and Delete, I think the option is to use POST (instead of GET for read and DELETE for delete). Is there any downside to this approach? Are there guidelines for implementing such batch operations?

Comment: You might wanna look at some of the patterns described [here](http://restalk-patterns.org/index.html). Especially the [POST-PUT Creation](http://restalk-patterns.org/post-put.html) or the [Long Running Operation with Polling](http://restalk-patterns.org/long-running-operation-polling.html) might be of interest to you. 
While your exact problem is not covered there, the advantages and disadvantages of those pattern are well stated so you might be able to derive some design ideas and problems that apply to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to communicate [operations that aren't worth standardizing](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post), then you should be using POST.

In particular, PUT has a specific meaning in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain, and you shouldn't be trying to hijack it.

A request body with DELETE is a bad idea.  Don't go there - [use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

A request body with GET is a bad idea.  You should either figure out a way to get the information you need into the target URI of the request (ie, each different body you might send is a unique resource) OR you should [use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

Using POST isn't a great answer, because you hide from the HTTP application the fact that the request semantics are effectively read only; hiding that information reduces the number of intelligent things that general purpose HTTP components can do.  POST is still a much better choice than trying to stick a body on GET.

---

At some point in the future, we expect the working group to produce some standard for new HTTP method aka GET-with-a-body, and that might give you additional options.